# How to stream a mp3 file music using live555?

Tags: streaming, mp3, live555

I want to write an application which server send a music to it's clients and clients play this music exactly simultaneously.After a lot of search around it , I found  live555 which streams a music. So how Can I stream a mp3 file to my clients using it's default code (testMP3Streamer & testMP3Receiver)? (I don't have internet connection while the program is running and I have to transmit my data over wifi)

```
char const* destinationAddressStr
#ifdef USE_SSM
= "232.255.42.42";
#else
= "239.255.42.42";
#endif
```

in the testMP3Streamer , there is a destination which determine a destination client , but I have more than one client!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **testOnDemandRTSPServer** or **testMP3Streamer** sample for stream Mp3 files. the address is specified there is a **multicast** address. you will be able to play those stream from multiple clients.